# Email send not working with smtp configuration through c#

Tags: c#, .net, web, smtp, smtpclient

I am trying to send email through c# code with smtp configuration but am getting following error:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
> connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Or sometimes I get exception like:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
> properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
> failed because connected host has failed to respond

My code is :

```
SmtpMail oMail = new SmtpMail("TryIt");
oMail.From = SenderEmail;
oMail.To = TxtEmail.Value;
oMail.Subject = "Password Reset";
string body = "Hello " + ",";
body += "<br /><br />Please click the following link to reset password";
body += "<br /><a href = '" + RedirectRegPage + "'>Click here</a>.";
body += "<br /><br />Thanks";
oMail.HtmlBody = body;
SmtpServer oServer = new SmtpServer("mail.ServerName.com");
oServer.User = //User EMail
oServer.Password = // User EmailPassword
oServer.Port = 465;
EASendMail.SmtpClient oSmtp = new EASendMail.SmtpClient();
oSmtp.SendMail(oServer, oMail);
Session["Message"] = "MailSent";
```

The email is being sent successfully through my Outlook . Can anyone please guide what i am missing here so that i can conclude to some resolution.

Comment: It depends what you have configured usually you bee to be accredited by the servers this can be by first receiving emails. So look at the help pages f rom your provider what he wants

Comment: The thing is that all parameters i.e. (ServerName, port, useremail, paswd) are exactly the same. I mean the outlook also should not been successfully sending mails

Comment: as i said your email hoster defines the rules, how you can send. For example mine expects before hand a get mesaages before i can send one, but that is also so enalbkled in my outlook. so read the help pages for your provider he will explain all

Comment: As you are using a [paid-for product](https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail), you can contact their [technical support](https://www.emailarchitect.net/support.aspx)

Comment: Can you try defining the connection type for your SMTP server? example: oServer.ConnectType = SmtpConnectType.Auto

Comment: I added this oServer.ConnectType = SmtpConnectType.ConnectSSLAuto; but the issue is same